# How do I link to another sheet in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to generate a list of hyperlinks in excel and link them dynamically to another cell in a different sheet.  Could someone explain how I need to format the reference?  Currently, it looks like this:

```
'p2r is one sheet
'sh is another
'Subaddress is currently linking to the correct location, wrong sheet.
    '(It's linking to [p2r]'s cells, not [sh]'s cells)

p2r.Hyperlinks.Add_
    Anchor:=p2r.Cells(p2rIndex, 1), _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=sh.Cells(round2, 2).Address, _
    TextToDisplay:=PrevRow
```

Thanks for the help!  I've seen others use a format like: Sheet!A1, but when I tried something like:

```
SubAddress:=sh & "!" & Cells(round2, 2).Address
```

I got no results of value.

Comment: To generate the "Sheet" part, you would need to use `sh.Name`, so try `SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name & "'!" & Cells(round2, 2).Address` (the extra `'`s are to ensure it continues to work if there are spaces, etc, in the sheet name).  You might also like to try `SubAddress:=sh.Cells(round2, 2).Address(External:=True)`

Comment: @YowE3K, this worked perfectly.  All I needed to do was add that (External:=True), and it took right off.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two modifications you could use to get your code working:

1. You could use

   `SubAddress:="'" & Replace(sh.Name, "'", "''") & "'!" & Cells(round2, 2).Address`

   in order to generate something of the form `SubAddress:="'Sheet name'!$A$1"`.

   (The bits in the formula dealing with `'`s are to allow it to still work if there are spaces, etc, in the sheet name.  If you know that won't occur, e.g. because you defined the sheet names and no-one else will be changing them, you could simplify it to `SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!" & Cells(round2, 2).Address`)

2. You could use

   `SubAddress:=sh.Cells(round2, 2).Address(External:=True)`

   which would generate something of the form `SubAddress:="'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet name'!$A$1"`